# Why SAX parser not working on phone but working on Emulator?

Tags: android, saxparser

i am getting following error while running app on phone but working on emulator.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(BMIConstant.Url + "ValidLoginUser");
    List<BasicNameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    password = etxt_pass.getText().toString().trim();
    username = etxt_user.getText().toString().trim();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Emailaddress", username));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));
    System.out.println("user name is--->"+username+ " password---->"+password);
    System.out.println(httppost.getRequestLine());

    try {
        UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httppost.setEntity(p_entity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();           
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        LoginHandler myLoginHandler = new LoginHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myLoginHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(responseEntity.getContent()));
        LoginParser myLoginParser = myLoginHandler.parser;
        System.out.println("return code is---->"+myLoginParser.getCode());

        id = Integer.parseInt(myLoginParser.getCode());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        removeDialog(0);
    }
```

01-11 12:47:15.194: W/System.err(7300): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 20, column 76: not well-formed (invalid token)
01-11 12:47:15.194: W/System.err(7300):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:523)
01-11 12:47:15.194: W/System.err(7300):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:482)
01-11 12:47:15.194: W/System.err(7300):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:320)
01-11 12:47:15.204: W/System.err(7300):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:277)
01-11 12:47:15.204: W/System.err(7300):     at com.apps.clx.bouncemein.WelcomeActivity.tryLogin(WelcomeActivity.java:258)
01-11 12:47:15.204: W/System.err(7300):     at com.apps.clx.bouncemein.WelcomeActivity$6.run(WelcomeActivity.java:161)
01-11 12:47:15.204: W/System.err(7300):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3707)
01-11 12:47:15.204: W/System.err(7300):     at com.apps.clx.bouncemein.WelcomeActivity.loadDataInView(WelcomeActivity.java:156)
01-11 12:47:15.204: W/System.err(7300):     at com.apps.clx.bouncemein.WelcomeActivity.access$1(WelcomeActivity.java:152)
01-11 12:47:15.204: W/System.err(7300):     at com.apps.clx.bouncemein.WelcomeActivity$3.onClick(WelcomeActivity.java:84)
01-11 12:47:15.204: W/System.err(7300):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-11 12:47:15.214: W/System.err(7300):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-11 12:47:15.214: W/System.err(7300):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-11 12:47:15.214: W/System.err(7300):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 12:47:15.214: W/System.err(7300):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-11 12:47:15.214: W/System.err(7300):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
01-11 12:47:15.214: W/System.err(7300):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 12:47:15.214: W/System.err(7300):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-11 12:47:15.214: W/System.err(7300):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)

please help me.

i am getting following error plese check it and let me know.

```
I/System.out(11616): result is:<html>
    01-11 16:09:42.415: I/System.out(11616):     <head>
    01-11 16:09:42.415: I/System.out(11616):         <title>Runtime Error</title>
    01-11 16:09:42.415: I/System.out(11616):         <style>
    01-11 16:09:42.415: I/System.out(11616):          body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
    01-11 16:09:42.415: I/System.out(11616):          p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
    01-11 16:09:42.415: I/System.out(11616):          b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
    01-11 16:09:42.415: I/System.out(11616):          H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
    01-11 16:09:42.415: I/System.out(11616):          H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
    01-11 16:09:42.415: I/System.out(11616):          pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):          .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):          .version {color: gray;}
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):          .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):          .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):         </style>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):     </head>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):     <body bgcolor="white">
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <span><H1>Server Error in '/BounceMeInWS' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <br><br>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):                <tr>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):                   <td>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):                       <code><pre>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616): &lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616): &lt;configuration&gt;
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):     &lt;system.web&gt;
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):         &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):     &lt;/system.web&gt;
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616): &lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):                   </td>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):                </tr>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             </table>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <br>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application&#39;s &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):                <tr>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):                   <td>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):                       <code><pre>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616): &lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616): &lt;configuration&gt;
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):     &lt;system.web&gt;
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):         &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):     &lt;/system.web&gt;
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616): &lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):                   </td>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):                </tr>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             </table>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):             <br>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616):     </body>
    01-11 16:09:42.425: I/System.out(11616): </html>
    01-11 16:09:42.445: I/System.out(11616): inside dialoge box
```

Comment: Can you print the contents of `responseEntity` (use `EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity)`) and attach to your question?

Comment: i have added contents of responseEntity check it.

Comment: Well, the problem isn't in your android code - your web service is crashing. You'd better go check the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates there is something wrong with your XML.

First, you should check that you get the correct reply from network. Look at the http response [status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

```
if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
    // it's ok, proceed with parsing
} else {
    // som error: retry, notify user, etc..
}
```

My guess is that you are trying to access the `localhost` (= `127.0.0.1`). Use `10.0.2.2` instead.

**Update:**
Wrong address or port would produce an exception not wrong response code. There must be some problem with the XML. Maybe an encoding issue? Can you post the offending XML here?

Comment: connecting to, for instance, an unresponsive host (e.g. localhost) or the wrong port gives you an exception, not a HTTP status code.

Answer (score 0):

Not well-formed (invalid token) normally resulted by a bad response xml, check your response xml string by following method:

HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.convertStreamtoString(responseEntity);

and check if this string is having any special character(for eg, '&') init. if it has, replace these characters.

Comment: thanks,i am getting server error while getting data from web service on device but i am able to get data successfully on emulator.

Comment: ok, then you need to check if you need to have some specific setting on server side application that does not accept connection from device side, or if you need to send some special parameters to server when you access webservice through device, and one more thing you may accessing network behind proxy in emulator/without proxy opposite of device.